# Understanding Legendre-fenchel Transform, looking for an easy example and intuition

Tags: real-analysis, random-variables, large-deviation-theory

Looking for help in understanding this transform. I have no background in real analysis but need this stuff for my research.

I hope someone can give me some light on the intuition behind this transform and better if you can provide some example I can work with.

Thanks in advance.

I already found some information related to it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2034891/legendre-fenchel-transform)

But, still not able to fully understand.

Thanks.

Comment: Some intuition for the Fenchel conjugate can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/624633/40119 and here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/500237/40119

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will answer my own question since I found a very good reading material which helped me to fully understand the topic.

If interested, take a look [here.](https://web.archive.org/web/20210518170441/http://www.onmyphd.com/print.php?p=legendre.fenchel.transform)